# How to disable or encrypt the data from sql server 14 when some one exports it to excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, encryption, sql-server-2014

Actually I already implemented the TDE . But I also want to encrypt the data when someone exports to excel. TDE only encrypt the database files. 
Or can you tell me if some one get the access the database how can I block the export option for him.

I am using sql server 2014 developer edition

Comment: you can't block it. If they have access to the database, they can query anything they like. Even without a direct export-to-excel function or something, they can just run a query and then copy/paste the results. If you don't want someone to copy the data, don't give them access to it. If you must give them access, then you make them sign a policy about what they can and can't do with the data, on pain of disciplinary action. You keep records of who has accessed what and when. And maybe you give it to them in a format that's more awkward to copy from, like PDF or something.

Comment: @ADyson Is there any other way where if someone exports data an automated mail sent to me?

Comment: as for encryption, I genuinely don't know if you can do that. But blocking an export and encrypting an export do not seem to be to be equivalent, to me. What's the end goal here?

Comment: If you log all access to the data, you could have a service/job/trigger which monitors the logs and sends emails when someone accesses it. Don't forget what I said, export / access are, to all intents and purposes, the same thing, due to copy/paste. You might find that an email every time someone queries it is a bit much, but certainly you should have logs and run reports from them regularly.

Comment: @ADyson actually I want to secure my database. I implemented TDE. What are the other things I do ?

Comment: "secure my database" is a very wide topic. You've encrypted it, you're clearly concerned about logging user access, and presumably you've set up users and roles to restrict access to just what people and applications actually need...so what else specifically are you concerned about? You could buy a whole book on database security as a general topic, it's not really something we can discuss in sufficient detail on SO. Have you got a more specific concern other than what I've already covered above?

Comment: @ADyson My concern is that if someone hacks my database then he cant get the data.

Comment: if someone hacks your database and succeeds and gaining entry as a valid user (or impersonating a valid user), then it's too late to protect your data, because they have all the rights of that user and can access the data. So you should focus your energy on preventing unauthorised access by protecting the database using encryption, network firewalls, restrictive permissions, and also creating the correct culture where users do not expose their credentials to others, either deliberately or accidentally. This last part is the hard part. Human beings are your weakest point.

Comment: On top of that you can, as I suggested, log what users are doing, and monitor/analyse that to try and detect unusual or suspicious activity, and also to help to trace the source of any breach if it does occur despite everything you've done. In truth everything I've said should apply to your whole network and all your organisation's data and applications, whether stored in databases or filesystems or wherever. The same basic precautions apply. Practical methods of doing so vary by the technology used and the organisation's exact circumstances. Like I said, it's a huge topic.

Comment: @ADyson Can you suggest me , which is better TDE or Column level encryption for a large application

Comment: no I can't, because it depends on much more than just knowing whether the applicaiton is "large" (and that in itself is a very subjective description - your definition of "large" may not be the same as mine). We would need to know a lot more detail to make a sensible choice. Like I said, this is a huge topic and you need to read up on it. If you feel you don't have the expertise to learn from the resources available, I suggest employing a DBA with experience in this area. The topic is too large and the possible variables to great for discussion on a forum like this.

Comment: And also security is too important to just guess or try and get random opinions for free from the internet. SO is good but there's no guarantee that those answering are actually giving the best advice. Other than a rather subjective "reputation" rating you've really got no idea if people are genuinely knowledgeable or not. With a simple coding question you can usually verify the answer easily, but not with a topic like this. Take the time to learn, and/or make the financial investment in the relevant expert who can pay full attention to the details of your specific circumstances.

Comment: @ADyson In server machine , windows authentication mode of sql server management studio automatically gets the login details in windows mode. I want to block this.If someone opens ssms , he should not get the server name to login.

Comment: you can easily google how to switch off windows authentication in SQL Server. But you aren't listening to me. Stop deciding on random changes and come up with a proper strategy. It's clear from your questions that you aren't sure what you're doing, so stop before you make an undocumented mess and come up with a plan and a set of standards to enforce which match your organisational requirements and your assessment of the potential threats. If you can't do it yourself, employ someone qualified to do so.

Comment: @ADyson actually I am working for a small company so, I have to do  every thing

Comment: ok well if they can't afford someone with the relevant expertise, then you'll have to do some training and some serious reading. I wouldn't want to approach this topic without that. Your employer should not expect you do implement this properly without allowing time for that (assuming that you didn't already claim the relevant knowledge without actually having it).